# how to write weight parallel to edge?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

In the following graph edge weight by default is written as horizontally, I want to write weight value parallel to edge between two nodes.

How may I write weight value parallel to the edge between two nodes?

```
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2.2cm,on grid]
          \node[state] (q_1)                {$f_1$};


          \node[state] (q_7) [below=of q_1] {$f_1$};
          \node[state] (q_13) [below=of q_7] {$f_1$};
          \node[state] (start) [left=of q_13] {$start$};
          \node[state] (q_19) [below=of q_13] {$f_1$};
          \node[state] (q_25) [below=of q_19] {$f_1$};


          \path[->] (start) edge                node [above] {0.0899} (q_1)
                    (start) edge                node [above] {0.1304} (q_7)
                    (start) edge                node [above] {0.3051} (q_13)
                    (start) edge                node [above] {0.2443} (q_19)
                    (start) edge                node [above] {0.1044} (q_25);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

How may I write weight value parallel to the edge between two nodes?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) For the future it would be better to post a compilable minimal document (like the one in my answer). That way potential answerers don't have to guess/find out which packages or libraries you use for your code to work (I never used `automata` before, for example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `sloped` option to align nodes along paths.

**EDIT:** Just to make this clearly visible to any future visitors (I already stated this in a comment below): You should never use constructs like `$start$` as that would mean a formula of `s*t*a*r*t` and not the word "start". If you want something written in italic, you can use `\itshape` in a group, or `\textit` as a macro taking an argument (so `{\itshape abc}` or `\textit{abc}`). In Ti*k*Z you can specify `\itshape` in a node's `font` option like `\node[font=\itshape]{abc}`. If you need a word in an otherwise mathematical context, you can use `\text` provided by `amsmath`, e.g., `\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2.2cm,on grid]
          \node[state] (q_1)                {$f_1$};


          \node[state] (q_7) [below=of q_1] {$f_1$};
          \node[state] (q_13) [below=of q_7] {$f_1$};
          \node[state] (start) [left=of q_13] {$start$}; % change this
          \node[state] (q_19) [below=of q_13] {$f_1$};
          \node[state] (q_25) [below=of q_19] {$f_1$};


          \path[->] (start) edge                node [above,sloped] {0.0899} (q_1)
          (start) edge                node [above,sloped] {0.1304} (q_7)
          (start) edge                node [above,sloped] {0.3051} (q_13)
          (start) edge                node [above,sloped] {0.2443} (q_19)
          (start) edge                node [above,sloped] {0.1044} (q_25);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to write dark line(in bold)?

Comment: @SANJAYGUPTA glad I could help. On this site however we say thank you by upvoting and accepting answers (accepting should be done after a reasonable amount of time to give other answerers a chance to post something better, and of course only accept if the answer solves your question). You'll get the privilege to upvote once you have enough reputation yourself.

Comment: @SANJAYGUPTA I don't quite understand what you mean with that? Do you want the line to be thicker? You can use the `thick` option for your `\draw` instead.

Comment: yes I want to make some of the line to be thicker not to all, where should i put thick in code?

Comment: Use `\path[->,thick] (start) edge node[above, sloped]{x} (y);` for those you want to be thick and only `\path[->] ...` for those you don't want to be thick.

Comment: @SANJAYGUPTA I just noticed, you shouldn't use `$start$`. That is semantically wrong, as that would mean you're using the formula `s*t*a*r*t` and not the word "start". If you want the word, leave out the `$`s (so just `{start}` for that node). If you want the word to be italic, use `[font=\itshape]{start}` for that node (adding `font=\itshape` to the node's options).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90983/discussion-between-sanjay-gupta-and-skillmon).